# Python - check if 1st element in list of tuples exists in string, if it does add 2nd element from tuple to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have string values called `cols` that have the column name and data type:

```
cols

_LOAD_DATETIME datetime,
_LOAD_FILENAME string,
_LOAD_FILE_ROW_NUMBER int,
_LOAD_FILE_TIMESTAMP datetime,
ID int
```

next I have this list of tuples:

```
comment_list = [('_LOAD_FILE_TIMESTAMP', 'TEST'), ('ID', 'ID of Account')]
```

I want to check if the 1st position element in `comment_list` exists in cols the first word of `cols`, if it does, add the word 'COMMENT' and  the 2nd position element to cols.

so cols should now look like:

cols

```
_LOAD_DATETIME datetime,
_LOAD_FILENAME string,
_LOAD_FILE_ROW_NUMBER int,
_LOAD_FILE_TIMESTAMP datetime COMMENT 'TEST',
ID int COMMENT 'ID of Account'
```

Comment: Is `cols` a list or string?

Comment: @AnnZen thanks for responding! I saw your answer but cols is string, not a list

Comment: Got it; updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to loop through each line in the string after calling the `str.split()` method on the string, and concatenate each modified string to a new string:

```
cols = '''_LOAD_DATETIME datetime,
_LOAD_FILENAME string,
_LOAD_FILE_ROW_NUMBER int,
_LOAD_FILE_TIMESTAMP datetime,
ID int'''

comment_list = [('_LOAD_FILE_TIMESTAMP', 'TEST'), ('ID', 'ID of Account')]

cols2 = ''
for col in cols.split(","):
    for comment in comment_list:
        strings = col.split()
        if comment[0] in strings:
            strings.append(f"COMMENT '{comment[1]}'")
            break
    cols2 += " ".join(strings) + "\n"

print(cols2)
```

Output:

```
_LOAD_DATETIME datetime
_LOAD_FILENAME string
_LOAD_FILE_ROW_NUMBER int
_LOAD_FILE_TIMESTAMP datetime COMMENT 'TEST'
ID int COMMENT 'ID of Account'
```